# Send Facebook server-side event using shortcode and Official Facebook Pixel plugin

Tags: facebook

I have installed and configured the Official Facebook Pixel plugin. Now I would like to create a shortcode that will trigger a selected server-side event.

`[myapp_fbevent event_name="test"]`

How can I implement such shortcode? I have inspected the plugin source code and came up with something like this:

```
function myapp_fbevent_shortcode($event_name) {
    do_action('send_server_event', $event_name);
}

add_shortcode('myapp_fbevent','myapp_fbevent_shortcode');
```

Is this a correct usage?

Comment: I'm not sure using a shortcode to raise a server side event makes sense? A shortcode event will be just be for the user loading the page, and you can inject custom 'fbq.track' lines in the main pixel code for that instead, e.g. [example in the documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/964258670337005) marked '3'.

Comment: The client-side javascript code can be blocked by the browser (Firefox tracking protection) or browser plugin (AdBlock). Using the shortcode with the event name  paramater will allow me easily triggering specific events for specific pages.